# VSCode does't recognize iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug a flutter app using VSCode but it doesn't find any devices and show the message `Cannot launch without an active device`.

I can launch the app using the command `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety` from the terminal but I want to do it using the VSCode debug tool.

Specs:

- macOS Big Sur 11.3
- VSCode 1.58.1
- Simulator iPhone 12, iOS 14.5
- XCode 12.5.1

my launch.json file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "console": "terminal",
            "args": ["--no-sound-null-safety"],
        }
    ]
}
```

my settings.json file:

```
{
    "dart.flutterAdditionalArgs": [
        "--no-sound-null-safety"
    ],
    "dart.vmAdditionalArgs": [
        "--no-sound-null-safety"
    ],
}
```

Comment: In my experience you need to quit vs code, launch Xcode, point the Locations tools at it, run a simple project in the simulator, then launch vs code.

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't work :(

Answer (score 38):

The problem is because the Xcode no setting the locations to command-line tools:

Go to `preferences > locations > Command Line Tools`

then select Xcode xx
[image]

Comment: Worked for me, but in my case the Xcode {version} was already selected but i had to re-select it for some reason.

Comment: same situation of @lorenzo, probably a bug

Comment: Same situation for me, I had to reselect it for some reasons.

Answer (score 8):

Open your XCode
Navigate to
Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools and Chose XCode in the dropdown.

This worked for me!

Answer (score 8):

run these two commands(I'm Mac user not windows, otherwise run flutter doctor, it should tell you the exact command to run) it should work:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

Answer (score 1):

The amazingly simple answer for me was to start the iOS Simulator I wanted to use in Xcode before trying to use it in VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

Navigating to Settings -> Locations -> Command Line Tools and choosing the current Xcode version worked for me. Even though Xcode is already selected, you must select it again. This will change it from "No Xcode Selected" to "/Applications/Xcode.app". This is for Xcode 15. The simulator will show up in Vscode immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you've have xcode in any other directory than Application, this may happen.

You may put xcode in your Application directory in mac os.